# Error parsing XML: hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

*Hello ,I am running my hibernate program but bellow error occur.....if any one

can solve plz help for that ...
this is my first program of hibernate i am running ..

**My hibernate.cfg.xml is==>**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ACER:1521:XE</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">system</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">SHREE</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>  
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>  \
```

Error===>

```
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: hibernate.cfg.xml(18) Content is not allowed in trailing section.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2010)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1922)
    at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:13)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 18 of document  : Content is not allowed in trailing section. Nested exception: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2002)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: You got an extra "\" at the last line [line 18]. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

change your last line from

```
</hibernate-configuration>  \
```

> remove this slash ---------------↑

to

`</hibernate-configuration>`

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. Your code should work. Also, please accept /up vote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: i have solve the above issue..now Network Adapter could  not establish the connection

Comment: Refer a tutorial online. That way it would be easy for you. The default port for MySQL is 3306. Try that.

Comment: I m using oracle ...sql server..Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ACER:11320:ORACLE11";
  String username="system";
  
  String password="shree";
  
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
  
  System.out.println("Conn establish...............");